# How do I inform the compiler that `getcontext` can return multiple times?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization, ucontext

[`getcontext`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/getcontext.html) can return multiple times.  For example, I have sketched a C program analogous to the one demostrated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation#Examples):

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ucontext.h>

struct communication {
        const ucontext_t *return_ctx;
        int return_value;
};

static void
test(ucontext_t *thisctx, struct communication *comm)
{
        int i = 0;
        assert(getcontext(thisctx) == 0);
        // getcontext will return 3 times with i having different values

        comm->return_value = ++i;
        setcontext(comm->return_ctx);
        assert(0);
}

int
main(void)
{
        ucontext_t mainctx, testctx;
        struct communication comm;
        char test_stack[SIGSTKSZ];

        assert(getcontext(&testctx) == 0);
        testctx.uc_stack.ss_sp = test_stack;
        testctx.uc_stack.ss_size = sizeof test_stack;
        makecontext(&testctx, test, 2,
                &testctx, &comm);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                // Rewind test's execution where 'getcontext' returns
                comm.return_ctx = &mainctx;
                assert(swapcontext(&mainctx, &testctx) == 0);
                assert(printf("%d\n", comm.return_value) > 0);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running it

```
$ gcc -std=gnu99 -O3 -o getcontext_test getcontext_test.c
$ ./getcontext_test
1
1
1
```

does not give expected `1 2 3` because the compiler thinks that `i` can only equal `1` when assigned to `comm->return_value`.

I can work this around by defining `i` `volatile`, however I would like a more canonical approach to this issue.

Comment: `int i = 0;` this variable is a _local_ variable, it will be initialized to 0 upon each call of `getcontext`, so `comm->return_value` will always be assigned 1 independently of the context.

Comment: There is no more canonical approach than declaring `i` as volatile. Since `getcontext()` is doing things outside the scope of standard C, there is no standard way to tell the compiler that it’s the case.  For a particular compiler, there might be a useful `#pragma` but it won’t be standardized.

Comment: In the absence of `volatile` in the declaration of `i`, the compiler is entitled to optimize the variable `i` out of existence and simply assign `1` to `comm->return_value`.  It is quite plausible that it does so, in fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A necessary (but maybe not sufficient) requirement for what you want is making `i` (in the `test` function; the duplication of name between functions of the identifier you're asking about is unfortunate) `volatile`. This is already a requirement in the standard (7.13.2.1 ¶3):

> All accessible objects have values, and all other components of the abstract machine have state, as of the time the longjmp function was called, except that the values of objects of automatic storage duration that are local to the function containing the invocation of the corresponding setjmp macro that do not have volatile-qualified type and have been changed between the setjmp invocation and longjmp call are indeterminate.

for objects that may be modified between successive returns of `setjmp`, so it makes perfectly good sense that you should (and should have to) do the same thing with `getcontext`.

For other reasons, it may be necessary for the compiler to be aware that `getcontext` return more than once. On GCC and compatible compilers (most anything but MSVC), you can achieve this with `__attribute__((__returns_twice__))`. However, the header that declared `getcontext` (or compiler internals) should already be doing something like this if it's needed.